# Is there a way in Excel to automatically import and update the word count of a Microsoft Word doc?

Tags: excel, automation, ms-word

I have an excel spreadsheet that tracks my writing progress, and each day I enter my current word count into the spreadsheet and have various calculations to keep me motivated and on track - things like "how many more days will this take if I write this much each day" and so on.

Is there any way I could automate this process so that Excel would automatically check for the most recent word count in the Word doc and import it? Or are there other ways I could achieve this?

I use the enterprise versions of Office, and it's all in the cloud.

Comment: *Is there any way I could automate this process ?* Yes, probably with VBA macro, but not sure if it's worth it. You could create a macro in Word that opens the Excel file, updates value with word count and closes the Excel file. It owuld save you just a few seconds unless you do this really really really often.

Comment: This can all be done without programming...